# How to stop Code Blocks from highlighting non-keywords?

Tags: formatting, codeblocks, color-scheme, code-formatting

I don't have an image, but when I type something like `back`, `begin`, `end`, `move` and others like that, Code Blocks highlights it. I can't seem to find where the settings are for it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I hate when IDEs treat non-reserved words like this, it confuses the hell out of people who are learning a new language.
Go to this file: CodeBlocks\share\CodeBlocks\lexers\lexer_cpp.xml
and delete whichever words you don't want to be highlighted.